# Elasticsearch buckets on results of aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization

I am using ELK 7.x. I would like a histogram or bar chart in Kibana on the results of an aggregation. As it's a bit abstract to explain, below is the equivalent SQL query.

```
select count(*) as no_of_docs, doc_type 
from documents
group by doc_type

15     pdf
21     doc
17     txt
 1     ppt
```

A histogram or any chart as below:

```
No of docs        Count of doc type 
(X-Axis)          (Y-Axis) 
1-10              1 [1 ppt occurrence in the 1-10 bucket]
11-20             2 [1 pdf, 1 txt occurrences in the 11-20 bucket]
21 and above      1 [1 doc occurrence in the 21 and above  bucket]
```

It may not be straightforward, but I do think it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with the below mapping and documents and accordingly created the a [Vertical Bar](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-visualizing.html#tutorial-visualize-bar) visualizer.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_docs
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "doc_type":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Documents:

```
POST my_docs/_doc/1
{
  "doc_type": "pdf"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/2
{
  "doc_type": "pdf"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/3
{
  "doc_type": "pdf"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/4
{
  "doc_type": "jpeg"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/5
{
  "doc_type": "jpeg"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/6
{
  "doc_type": "txt"
}

POST my_docs/_doc/7
{
  "doc_type": "txt"
}
```

### Sample Query and Response:

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "select count(*) as no_of_docs, doc_type from my_docs group by doc_type"
}

  no_of_docs   |   doc_type    
---------------+---------------
2              |jpeg           
3              |pdf            
2              |txt
```

### Kibana Visualizer:

**Step 1:**

First thing is you would require to create index pattern. You can check this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html) as how this could be done.

Basically visit **Management > Kibana > Index Patterns** and add the index i.e. `my_docs`

**Step 2:**

- Click on `Visualize` button on the left side of Kibana
- Once you do that, you should see `create new visualization`
- You should see various types of visualizer presented to you, scroll down and select `Vertical Bar` visualizer
- Now you should select the index on which this visualizer should be applied i.e. the index `my_docs`. Note that if you haven't created index pattern, this index would not show up.
- Notice the screen, it already has by default added doc_count as Y axis, all you need to do is configure X-axis
- Under the `Buckets` section click on Add and select X-axis
- Notice you should see X-axis get selected and that `Aggregation` field shows up.
- Select `Terms` and when you do that select `doc_type` in the `Field` section.
- Now click on Blue run button(it should show `Apply Changes` when you move your cursor on it) next to `Panel Settings` on the top of this section where you configure the fields.

Below is how the image appears for X-axis part:

[image]

Notice that your visualizer is ready. Below is how it appears in my machine for the above sample data:

[image]

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: What you have done is the standard use case. I do not want doc type (pdf/jpeg/txt) on x-axis, rather the count of them in buckets. It's like an outer query on top of the main query. Pls see my question again.